# Merge Values of Columns if Another Column is Duplicated

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataframe with ~10k rows.  There are about 100 rows that have duplicated PMID values and multiple levels of the phase variable.

```
> head(df_pn)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   phase [1]
  PMID      year month   day phase   date       monthly   
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <date>     <date>    
1 29287749  2017    12    31 Phase 1 2017-12-31 2017-12-01
2 29275332  2017    12    25 Phase 1 2017-12-25 2017-12-01
3 29127910  2017    11    12 Phase 1 2017-11-12 2017-11-01
4 29103339  2017    11     7 Phase 1 2017-11-07 2017-11-01
5 28964890  2017    10     2 Phase 1 2017-10-02 2017-10-01
6 28963724  2017    10     1 Phase 1 2017-10-01 2017-10-01
>
```

Here's the datable, sorted to make more sense of that:

```
> df_pn %>%
+   group_by(PMID) %>%
+   filter(n()>1) %>%
+   arrange(PMID)
# A tibble: 229 x 7
# Groups:   PMID [114]
   PMID      year month   day phase   date       monthly   
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <date>     <date>    
 1 10554105  1999    12    20 Phase 1 1999-12-20 1999-12-01
 2 10554105  1999    12    20 Phase 2 1999-12-20 1999-12-01
 3 10555022  1999    11    11 Phase 1 1999-11-11 1999-11-01
 4 10555022  1999    11    11 Phase 2 1999-11-11 1999-11-01
 5 10743796  2000     4     1 Phase 1 2000-04-01 2000-04-01
 6 10743796  2000     4     1 Phase 2 2000-04-01 2000-04-01
 7 11315914  2001     4    24 Phase 1 2001-04-24 2001-04-01
 8 11315914  2001     4    24 Phase 2 2001-04-24 2001-04-01
 9 11349741  2001     5    15 Phase 1 2001-05-15 2001-05-01
10 11349741  2001     5    15 Phase 2 2001-05-15 2001-05-01
# … with 219 more rows
```

I would like to combine the rows that have the same PMID and simultaneously merge the phase variable.  There would only be unique PMID values and there would be multiple new levels of the phase variable (instead of "Phase 1" and "Phase 2" there would be both of those plus "Phase 1 and Phase 2." To make this even more painful, there are a few PMID that have Phase 1 / Phase 2 / Phase 3. Annoying.

Have tried this a bunch of ways, using slice and group_by and joining and it's just not working well. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: PMID should be the only thing that varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming cases within `PMID` only differ on the variable `phase`, you could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df_pn %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-phase)) %>%
  summarise(phase = toString(phase))

# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   PMID, year, month, day, date [5]
      PMID  year month   day date       monthly    phase           
     <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           
1 10554105  1999    12    20 1999-12-20 1999-12-01 Phase 1, Phase 2
2 10555022  1999    11    11 1999-11-11 1999-11-01 Phase 1, Phase 2
3 10743796  2000     4     1 2000-04-01 2000-04-01 Phase 1, Phase 2
4 11315914  2001     4    24 2001-04-24 2001-04-01 Phase 1, Phase 2
5 11349741  2001     5    15 2001-05-15 2001-05-01 Phase 1, Phase 2
```

Comment: Excellent will try this and get back! Thanks for answering, will let you know how it works

Comment: Yep that did it! Very creative and succinct.